# MVC3 = >> return EmptyResult() When it's a good idea to return this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

when it's a good idea to return "EmptyResult()" from a Controller

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You would basically use it to signify that you are not doing anything with an action's 
result.

From MSDN:

> Represents a result that does nothing, such as a controller action method that returns nothing.

I have personally used on actions defined in an `AsyncController`, so if you have for instance an async action like:

```
public void SendMailAsync() { }
```

Basically an action in an `AsnycController`, you'll need a xxxCompleted action as well (by convention)

```
public virtual ActionResult SendMailCompleted
{
    // do whatever
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Since this is not an action meant to be called by a user but by a background task, I'm not going to do anything with the result anyway.

Comment: That's an interesting and very proper way of using it.

Comment: **1)** Is there a 'best practice' way to call an 'Async method'?  
**2)** How do you 'handle' the 'return EmptyResult()' response so that it get 'disregarded' in cases like the SendMailAsync() ?

Comment: @Filu - **1)** The very little I know about `AsyncController` I got from [here](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2010/03/29/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) and [here](http://www.aaronstannard.com/post/2011/01/06/asynchonrous-controllers-ASPNET-mvc.aspx). **2)** The best way to 'handle' an `EmptyResult` is *do nothing with it* ;) Seriously, just ignore you're even getting a result. If you can't ignore it, it means you probably need a normal result.

Comment: in regards to answer to 2) Assuming there is an application that has menu items with hide/show toggle buttons on them: What if you wanted to send off a flag value to the db saying to hide a selected menu item, for instance? Will the EmptyResult return type reload the whole view as blank?

Comment: @PAULDAWG - It depends on how you call that action. If you were using a normal `ActionLink` (or a simple link tag) then yes, you would get a blank page on your browser. If, on the other hand, you're using an ajax call, then no.

Comment: This though doesn't have anything to change the status code to something appropriate. While it could be in the `// do whatever`, the above could be read as suggesting you'd send no content with a `200` status code.

Answer (score 10):

I've used it when creating RESTful web services. When doing a POST or DELETE operation, for example, the HTTP status code can convey enough info in itself.

Comment: you can use Httpstatuscoderesult instead of emptyresult for that

Comment: @Mulki has a good point, especially since you'll have to set the 204 yourself manually anyway. `HttpStatusCodeResult` (or your own class derived from it) is clearer.

Answer (score 6):

When the ajax performs an action that doesn't need reflection/confirmation on the UI.

Comment: But if I return Empty ...doesn't the page become blank??
Or when it's an Ajax call, the result empty means ..nothing happens on the client ?

Comment: It depends on what you do with the empty result, if you painted the page to nothing, it would blank it, but I would recomend against it. So if I understand you right, you're correct.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming its the same as doing `return (null)` in the action. It could be useful at times. I've used it to `Response.Write` info to the output while debugging, but didn't need the remainder of the view rendered.

When you use it, you'll get a blank white page with nothing on it, unless you output something of your own.

Answer (score 4):

For a .NET Core solution (tested in v2.1), use:

```
return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent);
```

This will return a `StatusCodeResult` with the appropriate HTTP status code **[204 No Content](https://httpstatuses.com/204)**.

Answer (score 3):

for example: You can return empty result with status 401.

Comment: But would you return a 401 TEXT page that tells users ...not authorized ?

Comment: Also you have `HttpStatusCodeResult(401)` to do that

Answer (score 1):

The EmptyResult is a class in MVC which does not return anything, like Void method .

EmptyResult is used when you want to execute logic written inside the controller action method but does not want any result back to the view then EmptyResult return type is very important . 
It does not require to add the view.